# Expression with postgis

Tags: postgis-2.0, mapserver

I'm using mapserver and PostGis and I want to draw a geometric table in mapserver. The trouble is when I connect mapserver to PostGis and I want to draw the objects but in different colours. I mean I have this code

```
LAYER
NAME "poligono"
STATUS ON
CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
CONNECTION "host=localhost user=*** dbname=ejemplo password=*** "
DATA " geom from prueba using srid=4258"
TYPE LINE   
PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4258"
END
CLASS
    OUTLINECOLOR 0 255 255

END
```

And the table has 3 columns (gid[PK], name, geom), I want to change the colour for the different names. I tried whith

```
CLASSITEM "name from prueba"
CLASS
    EXPRESSION "Distrito 1"
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255

    EXPRESSION "Distrito 2"
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 255 255

    EXPRESSION "Distrito 1"
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 128 255
```

But it doesn`t work. What do I made wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it.

```
CLASSITEM name
CLASS
    EXPRESSION "Distrito1"
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
END
CLASS
    EXPRESSION "Distrito2"
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 255 255
END
CLASS
    EXPRESSION "Distrito3"
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 128 255
END
```

Comment: Could you add a comment on what you changed, please?

Comment: I changed the CLASSITEM, I put only the name of the column and I put the different EXPRESSIONs in different CLASSes.